# R strange behavior with data.table and grep subsetting columns

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I am trying to construct rowMeans for a subset of columns of a data table.  The code works if using a data frame, but not as a data table.  Why?

Minimal example -- the code below does not produce a 10x10 output:

```
IDnum <- c(101:110)
Name <- LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
minExample <- as.data.table(replicate(10,sample(0:5,10,rep=TRUE)))
minExample <- cbind(IDnum, Name, minExample)
grep("V",names(minExample))
#-- Intermediate output omitted

minExample[ , grep("V", names(minExample))]
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

But this does produce the correct (10x10) output:

```
minExample[ , 3:12]
```

However, converting to a data frame again produces the expected behavior:

```
minExample2 <- as.data.frame(minExample)
grep("V", names(minExample2))
minExample2[ , grep("V",names(minExample2))]

Row V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9  V10
1   2  3  5  5  1  3  2  1  3   1
2   4  3  0  1  5  3  0  5  2   3
3   1  2  0  2  2  4  4  0  4   0
4   3  4  5  4  0  0  2  0  0   3
5   2  2  4  4  5  2  1  4  2   2
6   5  3  3  1  1  2  0  5  1   4
7   4  2  2  0  3  1  4  0  5   1
8   0  4  3  2  2  2  2  0  3   5
9   4  3  3  5  4  1  2  0  5   0
10  5  5  0  3  4  4  0  0  1   5
```

Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minExample[ , grep("V", names(minExample)), with = FALSE]
```

As for why this is the case, check out the first entry in the data.table package documentation and the discussion of the with argument there. By default, `with=TRUE` meaning that expressions in the j position are treated as variables within the data.table. If you specify `with=FALSE` then you treat them as a vector of column names. In your syntax, you've supplied a character vector for the j position. Those are characters, not variables (within the data.table), and so they're not recognized. It's the same reason why `A=2` then `A+5` works, but `A=2`, `"A" + 5` does not.

Comment: Can you please explain why "with" is needed, or refer to documentation section that would explain?  Why does it work with a data frame but not a data table?

Comment: @ProfessorE Check out the first entry in the data.table package documentation and the discussion of the `with` argument there.  By default, `with=TRUE` meaning that expressions in the `j` position are treated as variables within the data.table.  If you specify `with=FALSE` then you treat them as a vector of column names.  In your syntax, you've supplied a character vector for the `j` position.  Those are characters, not variables (within the data.table), and so they're not recognized.  It's the same reason why `A=2` then `A+5` works, but `A=2`, `"A" + 5` does not.